# Linq Contains in one query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a List and i want to write  a query about List's ids Contains specific table id.

i Write this and running true but i want to write all in same query..

```
List<int> tempList=yetkiUygulamaList.Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
query = query.Where(x => tempList.Contains(x.Uygulama.Id));
```

Wrong Query

```
query = query.Where(x => yetkiUygulamaList.Select(y =>y.Id).ToList().Contains(x.Uygulama.Id));
```

Comment: in the "wrong query", what happens if you remove the `.ToList()` ?

Answer (score 0):

ToList() materilizes by executing the query, and after that there is no way for NHibernate to understand that the first query should be included as a subquery.

Just remove the useless ToList():

```
IQueryable<int> tempList = yetkiUygulamaList.Select(y => y.Id);  // removed here
query = query.Where(x => tempList.Contains(x.Uygulama.Id));
```

The above code will generate a single SQL query. If you want to stick it all in one C# code line, just get rid of the intermediary variable:

```
query = query.Where(x => yetkiUygulamaList.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Uygulama.Id));
```

Comment: this querys execute but i want to write one query to solve it. Thanks  for advice

Comment: @user990513 Not sure what you're aiming for... the code I show will generate a single SQL query. If you want fewer lines of C# code, you can just remove the intermediary variable. I've updated my answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

this must works

```
query = query.Where(x => yetkiUygulamaList.Any(y=>y.Id == x.Uygulama.Id));
```

Comment: same error occur. "System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported." query is a IQueryable<Rol> variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform a **join**, it would be more simple and suitable in your case.

If I understand, `query` is a "collection" of a class (let's call it **`AObj`**) containing a property `Uygulama` and the class `Uygulama` contains a property `Id` and `yetkiUygulamaList` is a "collection" of `Uygulama`

```
//will return a IEnumerable<AObj>
IEnumerable<AObj> query = query.Join(yetkiUygulamaList, a => a.Uygulama.Id, u => u.Id, (a,u)=>a);
```